# Why is my working directory view empty?How to set the working directory view

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Why is my working directory view empty?
How to set the working directory view

```
Working directory view: ** NONE **
```

How to set it?

```
[shibanis@linuxserver206 C-T3-P-fad-viewstore7]$ ct pwv
Working directory view: ** NONE **
Set view: hdbu_iop_shibanis_vu
```

And:

```
View details:[shibanis@linuxserver206 C-T3-P-fad-viewstore7]$ ct lsview -long hdbu_iop_shibanis_vu
Tag: hdbu_iop_shibanis_vu "san to nas storage"
  Global path: /net/in0oianas002/in0oianas002_SAS_U1/C-T3-P-fad-viewstore7/hdbu_iop_shibanis_vu.vws
  Server host: andd011
  Region: AND_DSLAM
  Active: YES
  View tag uuid:8e18a9d4.b2c511e5.8058.78:ac:c0:bb:69:2c
View on host: andd011
View server access path: /net/in0oianas002/in0oianas002_SAS_U1/C-T3-P-fad-viewstore7/hdbu_iop_shibanis_vu.vws
View uuid: 8e18a9d4.b2c511e5.8058.78:ac:c0:bb:69:2c
View owner: adcc/shibanis
```

Command used to create view:(sample)

```
/usr/atria/bin/cleartool mkview -tag iop5_shibanis -host andd011 -hpath /net/in0oianas002/in0oianas002_SAS_U1/C-T3-P-fad-viewstore7/iop5_shibanis.vws -gpath
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a dynamic view has been set with [`cleartool setview`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm) (and it is set, since your pwn shows your view has set), it uses a view context '/'.
That means your path within that view becomes: `/vobs/aVob/path/to/a/file`.

But that also means you need to make sure:

- a vob is mounted: `cleartool mount /vobs/avob`
- your config spec does select that vob: look at `cleartool catcs` output to check the selection rules.